# Handle ties when searching through arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

In my assignment, I have to make a room booking program. There is an option to count the rooms made and show the room with the most seats. What I am trying to do is show more than one room if there are two rooms with the most seats (tie). I have it working right now to print out the room with the most seats, I am just confused on how to implement the ties.

Class to find largest room

```
public static void roomCount(ArrayList<Room> rooms) {
    int largestRoom = 0;
    int largestNumOfRooms = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rooms.size(); i++) {
    if (rooms.get(i).getNumberOfSeats() > largestNumOfRooms) {//Determine largest room
            largestNumOfRooms = rooms.get(i).getNumberOfSeats();
            largestRoom = rooms.get(i).getRoomNumber();
        }
    }
```

Room class

```
     public class Room {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
private int roomNumber;
private int numberOfSeats;
private String reservedBy = "";
private boolean reserved;
private boolean hasSmartBoard;

/**
 * Get the attribute values from the user.
 */

public Room(int roomNumber) {
    this.roomNumber = roomNumber;

}


public void getRoomDetailsFromUser() {

    System.out.print("Enter number of seats: ");
    numberOfSeats = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Does this classroom have a smart board? (Y/N)");
    hasSmartBoard = input.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y");

}

public boolean isHasSmartBoard() {
    return hasSmartBoard;
}

public void setHasSmartBoard(boolean hasSmartBoard) {
    this.hasSmartBoard = hasSmartBoard;
}

public int getNumberOfSeats() {
    return numberOfSeats;
}

public void setNumberOfSeats(int numberOfSeats) {
    this.numberOfSeats = numberOfSeats;
}

public String getReservedBy() {
    return reservedBy;
}

public void setReservedBy(String reservedBy) {
    this.reservedBy = reservedBy;
}

public boolean isReserved() {
    return reserved;
}

public void setReserved(boolean reserved) {
    this.reserved = reserved;
}


public int getRoomNumber() {
    return roomNumber;
}

/**
 * Update the room to reserved and get the reserved by.
 */

public void reserveThisRoom(){
    this.reserved = true;
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the person reserving this room: ");
    reservedBy = input.nextLine();
}

 /**
 * Update the room to not reserved and clear the reserved by.
 */

public void releaseThisRoom(){
    this.reserved = false;
    reservedBy = "";
    System.out.println("Room has been released\n");


}

public String toString() {
    String output = "\n\n******************************"
            + "\nRoom Number: " + roomNumber
            + "\nNumber of Seats: " + numberOfSeats
            + "\nReserved By: " + reservedBy
            + "\nReserved: " + reserved
            + "\nSmart Board: "+ hasSmartBoard;
    return output;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of storing largestRoom in a `int` you can use `List` for that. so you can do the followings

```
List<Integer> largestRoom = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if (rooms.get(i).getNumberOfSeats() >= largestNumOfRooms) {//Determine largest room
        largestNumOfRooms = rooms.get(i).getNumberOfSeats();
        largestRoom.add(rooms.get(i).getRoomNumber());
    }
```

Also you need to return values from this method.

Comment: when I use that I get an error saying int cannot be deferenced

Comment: sorryy coulldn't understand your comment. have you change the largestRoom to ArrayList<Room> ?

Comment: where would I change the largestRoom to ArrayList<Room>?

Comment: where you have declared the variable. is it your code or you just copied from somewhere?

Comment: This is obviously my code I didn't understand your comment

Comment: ok , my bad sorry. as I have mentioned in answer.. right now you are using integer value to store the room number of largest room. Instead of that use an arraylist so that you can store multiple value. so when you find a room with largestroomcount you can add that room number in that list

Comment: I changed the largestRoom to an ArrayList, however I get a new error saying no suitable method found for add(int) the error is at   largestRoom.add(rooms.get(i).getRoomNumber());

Comment: sorry my typo mistake.. use the List<Integer> type.

Comment: it works now and shows the rooms with the most seats, but will only show the most recent entered room number, this was the output after I tested putting room 9 as the last entered room -- Largest Room is #[9, 9, 9] with 6seats

Comment: can you please check the input List rooms also .. and check what are the room number values of all the rooms with seat 6

Answer (score 0):

Make another `ArrayList` for the *room-numbers*. Like:

```
List<Integer> largestRoom = new ArrayList<Integer>();
if (rooms.get(i).getNumberOfSeats() > largestNumOfRooms) {
        largestNumOfRooms = rooms.get(i).getNumberOfSeats();
        largestRoom.clear();
        largestRoom.add(rooms.get(i).getRoomNumber());
}else if(rooms.get(i).getNumberOfSeats()==largestNumOfRooms){
    largest.add(rooms.get(i).getRoomNumber())
}
```

Now, the `largestRoom` has the *room numbers* you need.

Comment: Whenever I run this code, it only prints out the most recent room, it will see that there is a tie but it only shows the most recent entered room that encountered a tie